# How to collaborate on a Flex project?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I shall be working with my classmates over a Flex project, and we would need to collaborate for this.

Each of us will be developing modules, and we would like to use version controlling.

We've never done this for a Flex project, those who have done so before, can you please give us a few leads. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way in which the version controlling system compiles the mxml files by itself if checked in to the repository?

Comment: Hey all, I found this article and looks like this is what I needed from the beginning- http://www.flashmagazine.com/Tutorials/detail/setting_up_subversion_with_adobe_flex_3/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need version control system. First choice is SVN. It has good eclipse plugin (http://subclipse.tigris.org/). You are able to find a free svn hosing (google code, source forge, open svn, assembla). SVN is a centralized system - you need a server.

New trends says that distributed version control systems are better. You don't need a server. Three most popular are Git, Mercurial and Bazaar. They have explorer plugins ( Tortoise...) and maybe eclipse plugins. They work with servers too but shared disk is good too. Google code provides Mercurial server, but you are able to find free hosing.

In Flex projects remember not to version .settings folder and files : 
 .actionScriptProperties 
 .flexProperties 
 .project

Comment: We use SVN here and we only version control the src folder (but that's all we work in). I recommend SVN as well

Comment: Think about versioning swc libs, some embeded assets (icons etc.), .properties files. My rule is to version everything that is needed to build project besides the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion and Git are two widely used version control systems. If you have access to a server I would use subversion. There are arguments to be made for both Subversion and Git, but I find that subversion is easier to get started with although this is a personal opinion. For info on subversion check out this good book that explains what it is, how to install it, and how to use it.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch01.html